# Audo adjust form size fort different font size

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

[image: Wrong re-sized form]

See the above picture. On the right hand side I have the application running on a windows PC with normal font size (100%), on the left side is same application with font size set to 125% (This is set in screen preferences). As you can see the top-left 2 buttons are missing.

The form property .AutoScaleMode = Font, which should theoretically fix this issues but it does not. 
All left column buttons have Anchor = Left | Bottom. If I set it to Left | Top, then the bottom 2 buttons won't be visible.

How to fix this issue with the less amount of work? I have about 100 forms with such behavior.

Thx

Comment: You did something to prevent the window from getting tall enough.  Impossible to tell from a screenshot of course.

Comment: Yes indeed, in form.OnLoad I have Height = 312, which works as expected under normal font size. How shall I adjust this dimension regarding to the font size? Is there a multiplier that I can get from system information?

Comment: Yet again no hint whatsoever why you wrote that.  Just delete it.

Comment: I can't deleted it. Under that button I have a TextBox which must be hidden when app starts. That's why I'm forcing the form height. After some actions that textbox becomes visible, when I'm just changing the form height to needed one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't deleted it. Under that button I have a TextBox which must be hidden when app starts.

Just don't hard-code the Height property of the form, set it to the TextBox' Top property.  Or a bit less.  Also note that Height isn't the correct property to use, it is affected by the size that the user selected for the window title font.  So your form can already misbehave regardless of the video adapter's DPI setting.  You want to set the ClientSize property instead, like this:

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
        this.ClientSize = new Size(this.ClientSize.Width, SomeTextBox.Top);
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
```

With the further detail that this must be done in the form's Load event, as shown.  When it fires, the form has been rescaled so you'll know how tall to make it.  The constructor is too early.